# Why callback is not firing on button click?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-login

I am using a react npm called `react-facebook-login` to create a log-in button .The problem is that callback of the button component does not return anything.

This is the button component in which i am creating the button

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login'

export default class Facebook extends Component {


    state = {
        isLoggedin: false,
        userID: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        picture: ''
    }

    responseFacebook = response => {
        console.log(response);
    }

    componentClicked = () => console.log("clicked");


    render() {
        let fbContent;

        if(this.state.isLoggedin){
            fbContent =null;
        }
        else {
          console.log("test");
          fbContent = (
          <FacebookLogin
          appId="xxxxxxx"
          autoLoad={true}
          fields="name,email,picture"
          onClick={this.componentClicked}
          callback={this.responseFacebook} />)  
        }


        return <div>{fbContent}</div>

    }


}
```

The onClick event works the callback doesn't.

*Note that I have censored the `appId` its correct in my code.

Comment: Is this your component? If so, please provide code for that..

Comment: No, this is not my component , it is a default component from the npm i am using.

Comment: How you are using `FacebookLogin`? where you are importing the same. post the complete code

Comment: Can you try like this `callback={(response) => this.responseFacebook(response)}`

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code when working with functional component,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';

const responseFacebook = (response) => {
  console.log(response);
}

const componentClicked = () => console.log("clicked");

ReactDOM.render(
  <FacebookLogin
    appId="xxxxxxxxxx"
    autoLoad={true}
    fields="name,email,picture"
    onClick={componentClicked}
    callback={responseFacebook} />,
  document.getElementById('demo')
);
```

When working with class component

```
import React from 'react';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  responseFacebook(response) {
    console.log(response)
  }

  componentClicked(){
     console.log("clicked");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FacebookLogin
        appId="1088597931155576"
        autoLoad={true}
        fields="name,email,picture"
        onClick={componentClicked}
        callback={this.responseFacebook}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

[Ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login).

Also check this - [Permissions Reference - Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)

**Update**

Don't do this,

```
export default class Facebook extends Component {...} //dont export your component on same line
```

Instead you should do this,

```
class Facebook extends Component {...}

export default Facebook
```